# cascade persist with  JPA

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have two tables as shown in the following diagram :
[image]

as you saw this is a very simple example,SQL code relating to this is:

```
CREATE TABLE mere (
idmere INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nom VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(idmere)
);

CREATE TABLE fil (
idfil INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
mere_idmere INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
nom VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(idfil, mere_idmere),
FOREIGN KEY(mere_idmere)
REFERENCES mere(idmere)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

With Netbeans I created two entities and two JpaController(related to the created entities):
[image]

when inserting new lines I received this error(but a new line is inserted only in the table Mere):

```
Grave: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at testvirugule.FilJpaController.create(FilJpaController.java:37)
at testvirugule.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

**UPDATE**

my new source code:

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testvirugulePU");
 MereJpaController mjc=new MereJpaController(emf);

 FilJpaController fjc=new FilJpaController(emf);

 Mere m=new Mere(null,"mere1");
 FilPK fpk=new FilPK();
 Fil f=new Fil(fpk,"fils1");
 java.util.List<Fil> lf=new ArrayList<Fil>();
 lf.add(f);
 m.setFilList(lf);

 mjc.create(m);
```

but i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Could not find   entity for id: testvirugule.FilPK[ idfil=0, mereIdmere=0 ]
at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.getReference(EntityManagerImpl.java:1279)
at testvirugule.MereJpaController.create(MereJpaController.java:44)
at testvirugule.Main.main(Main.java:31)
   Java Result: 1
```

how to fix this problem ? thanks.

Comment: You have a null pointer exception. You need to narrow it down. Use the debugger.

Comment: done, and question is Updated , thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPE is one of the *easiest* exceptions to fix, because the stack trace tells you the line and the file at which the problem occurred.  A simple inspection in a text editor, with line numbers displayed, will often do the trick.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at testvirugule.FilJpaController.create(FilJpaController.java:37)
at testvirugule.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Go to line 37 in your `FilJpaController` and look at every object reference on that line.  One of them is null because you didn't initialized it properly.

Comment: sorry I forgot to put setFilList(lf) to bind the instance(m) to the list of Fil(lf); my question is rather, how to make a cascading persist?

Comment: I'd concentrate on the NPE first.  One to a customer, please.

Comment: in my previous code , just i have forgot to put f.setMere(m); from that comes the NPE, but the problem in the database the idFil value does not increment it is always at **0** ...  after reading this: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/store#Cascading_Persist_   I changed my code but still no result... any help how to insert the list of **Fil** (lf) automatically ??